# Is there any event to tell me a process is waiting for an input?

Tags: c#, wpf, process, redirectstandardoutput

I am processing a Tex file by starting a `Process` like this one:

```
process p1 = new Process();
p1.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\texlive\\2012\\bin\\win32\\pdflatex.exe";
p1.StartInfo.Arguments = FileName;
p1.consuleProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
p1.consuleProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p1.consuleProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p1.consuleProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p1.consuleProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
p1.Start();
p1.consuleProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
p1.consuleProcess.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(p1_OutputDataReceived);
```

I display the output strings in a `TextBox` by handling *OutputDataReceived* event.

If there were an error in the Tex file, a line should be written in *StandardInput*. I think there is no event that can tell me, when the process is waiting for an input; So I thought, I can check *OutputDataReceived* event to see when the condition: *e.Data == "?"* is true. But, the problem is that the *StandardInput* needs an input, just before firing *OutputDataReceived*  event with *e.Data=="?"*

So, what can I do to see when the process is waiting for an input?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you mean but are you after something like

```
p1.WaitForInputIdle(NumberofMilisecondstoWait)
```

Update:

Maybe something like this

```
  public void test()
        {
            p1.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(p1_OutputDataReceived);
        }

        void p1_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```